# How do I iterate over variables in R from a Python perspective?

Tags: r, variables, loops

Let's say I have this variable in R, `data`:

```
data.orange.lm = lm(...)
data.orange.avg = mean(...)
data.orange.sd = sd(...)
data.pear.lm = lm(...)
data.pear.sd = sd(...)
...
data.plum.sd = sd(...)
data.plum.summary = summary(lm(...))
```

How can I programmatically iterate over `data`? In Python `iteritems` for a `dictionary` will provide you with keys and the respective values. Is there a R equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store everything in a nested list:

```
data[["orange"]][["lm"]] = lm(...)
data[["orange"]][["avg"]] = mean(...)
data[["orange"]][["sd"]] = sd(...)
data[["pear"]][["lm"]] = lm(...)
data[["pear"]][["sd"]] = sd(...)
```

Then use the `apply` family of commands.

Comment: Reading the `apply` stuff now. So I should wrap all the actions (ie, outputting to charts, files, tables, etc) in functions, and then `apply` them the items (ie lm, mean, sd, etc) to the functions?

Comment: @c00kiemonster, you want your objects in a list, which you can access using apply family. One of the arguments for this family of functions is a (custom) function. You can write this custom function in a way that you read lm, avg, sd... In effect, an `lapply` function will iterate through orange and pear, and in your function, you will have lm, avg and sd available to do whatever.

Comment: @c00kiemonster:  That's the idea.  Roman has given you further detail.  Basically your function that's being applied will have access to an object (call it x) which is a list of length three with names "lm", "avg", and "sd".  Then you can do whatever you like with that list (including run another apply!).  I'm partial to sapply for ease of use, but it's simplify default can cause trouble if you're not careful.

Answer (score 0):

For data that is a bit like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  fruit = rep(c("orange", "pear", "plum"), each = 10),
  value = rnorm(30)
)
```

You can use `tapply` to get stats by fruit, and `sapply` to loop over functions.

```
fns <- c("mean", "sd")
stats <- sapply(fns, function(f) with(data, tapply(value, fruit, f)))
```

(If some of your functions don't return single numbers, then use `lapply` rather than `sapply`.)